# In the code below the createappcontainer is not rendereing any page . getting only white screen with no errors

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

```
const AuthStack = ({pages, Home, Landing}) =>{
console.log('Home: ', Home)
  const Astack = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: Home},
    Landing: {screen: Landing},
    Login: {screen: pages.Login},
    SignUp: {screen: pages.SignUp},

  }));
return <Astack />
}


export default class Template extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      auth,
      pages,
      home_page,
      landing_page,
      sidebar,
      sidebar_links,
      logout_in_sidebar,
      logout_in_header,
      logout_icon,
      custom_back_button,
    } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props ,"start pages props")

return <AuthStack pages={pages} Home={SideBar} Landing={landing_page} />;

  }
```

please help here in the authstack if i render the pages it renders but when i render Astack it doesnt i m frustrated dont know what is missing here